# Android maps v2 API; Polygon does not fill correctly

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I attempting to draw a filled Polygon using the v2 google maps API.  If I draw a standard retangle everything looks great.  If I try to something different like a arrow head the lines draw, but they do not fill. The app allows the user to define the points by interacting on the map).

In the example below, if you run the code segment below as is, it will draw an arrow like image that aims to the lower left.  The outline draws, but the map doesn't fill.

If you comment the "bad point" section and uncomment the "good point" line, the map draws and fills correctly.

Does anyone have any advice on what I can try to get these points to draw and fill correctly?

```
private void drawTest() {
    PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    rectOptions.add(new LatLng(44.97437590304863,-93.27457655221224)); // bad point
    //rectOptions.add(new LatLng(44.99098216930516,-93.27247872948647)); // good point
    rectOptions.add(new LatLng(44.977891781610175,-93.2605804502964));
    rectOptions.add(new LatLng(44.95120423204544,-93.26962251216173));
    rectOptions.add(new LatLng(44.97884376398687,-93.29010352492332));

    rectOptions.fillColor(0x50880000);
    rectOptions.strokeWidth(5);

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(44.97437590304863, -93.27457655221224),13));
    mPropOverlay.add(mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions));
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to add screenshots showing filled and unfilled polygons? To be able to do that, you need to have at least 10 reputation, which you can get by answering correctly one question.

Comment: It seems like you found a bug in GoogleMaps API V2. The behavior is absolutely reproducible from your description and I guess it has to do with the polygon being concave using the bad point and being convex using the good point. But according to Google's documentation concave polygons should work also. You should file a bug report for GoogleMaps.

Comment: I will write up a new report for GoogleMaps later today if nobody has a solution for this issue.  It's so easy to reproduce that I fear that I'm just missing an option.

Comment: I have written up the issue on Google's bug tracker; Please star so it gets looked at: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6197&q=apitype%3AAndroid2%20type%3ADefect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

Comment: So you got your ans or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by Google Maps v2 API v6.5; https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6197&q=apitype%3AAndroid2%20type%3ADefect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

Is the incident that I reported and google fixed.

Answer (score -1):

It has fixed since Play services 6.5